# how to assign a id to canvas in the three.js application

Tags: javascript, three.js, html5-canvas

I have created a render object in three.js and connect it with DomElment, shown as followed

```
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
            antialias: true
        });
renderer.setClearColor( 0xAAAAAA, 1 );
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.getElementById('webgl-container').appendChild(renderer.domElement);
```

so now three.js automatically create a canvas inside the webgl-container div, but now I want to give a canvas a id, how could I do it

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Have you tried :

```
renderer.domElement.id = 'YourIDName';
```

Answer (score 1):

A current approach that works well is to pass your canvas ID to the renderer when you create it:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas: canvas});
```